# Cloud Storage Triggers To Cloud Functions Stopped Working all of a sudden

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

We are using background Cloud Function with Cloud Storage Trigger (i.e. which gets triggered on Finalize/Create event from Cloud Storage Bucket in the same Google App Engine project).
These Cloud Functions process file uploads on some Bucket in Cloud Storage of same application. Files get written to these bucket folders continuously for 2-3 days and Cloud functions process every File based on Storage Trigger associated to it.

We ran this process on Saturday, 07 Sep 2019 at  07:19 am IST. This was working file till 09:27pm IST in evening the same day. 
After then, Cloud Storage triggers stopped working and did not trigger Cloud Functions.
Triggers only worked next day after outage of 5-9 hours when we tested again.

We did not see any logs regarding ERROR on Cloud Storage and Cloud Function.
Neither there were any Quota issues in the target bucket.

Though it has started working now, but We are not sure what was wrong and would like to be aware of the cause of failure.
This is business critical module hence no such outage can be overlooked.
Help us locate the root cause of this failure.

Comment: Only Google can help you with this issue: Open a new issue here: https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/

Comment: Yeah, created a Private Bug report with Google for this.

Comment: Update: Got Google team's response on this. As per them, the storage triggers affected due to some outage in US-Central region that day for some hours.